# How do I reset the github settings in the terminal for my computer (switching github profiles)

Tags: git, macos, github

I've been trying to straighten out things with git. I keep getting (or should I say 'gitting') errors that are related to the terminal trying to push git commits to a repo that doesn't exist anymore and I'm trying to send the commits to a new github profile.

**So I just want to somehow change the terminal git setup to reset so I can re-set it up. How do I reset it so its like I never set it up? I'm at the end of my rope.**

Is there any way to complete reset or erase and uninstall and then reinstall git. I've tried what both of the current answers have suggested but I still keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. First `cd` into your git folder.
2. show all shortnames for remote repositories for this git folder by `git remote` (there will be just `origin`) - or show all short names with their full URLs by `git remote -v` (verbose).
3. remove your original remote by `git remote rm origin` or
   rename it to `old_origin` by `git remote rename origin old_origin`. 
   Check changes you made by `git remote -v`.
4. Create repository in your new github profile (`<username>`) with the name `<repo>`
   Let's say username is `mynewme` and repo is `mynewrepo`
5. add the new repo for this git folde by `git remote add <shortname> git://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git`, here - name the new repo now `origin` but antoher shortname would do it, too ...
   `git remote add origin git://github.com/mynewme/mynewrepo.git`.
   By adding different repos with different shortnames, you can hold several git repos in parallel and distinguish them when pushing/pulling/updating your local git to/from them.
6. push to your new repo `git push <shortname> <branchname>`, here, since we name to repo with shortname `origin` it is the well known `git push origin master` again,
   which you can shorten to `git push` (since `origin` and `master` are default).

Since your new repo is called `origin` - this is the default remote repo for your git  folder.

Here again all commands:

```
cd /path/to/my/git/folder # your path to your git folder!
git remote -v # show all remote repo addresses with shortname at beginning
git remote rm origin # or: git remote rename origin old_origin
    # you can rename it later back or remove repos with these commands!
git remote -v # check changes!
git remote add origin git://github.com/mynewme/mynewrepo.git 
    # new shortname and new repo's address
git remote -v # check adding!
git push origin master # or just: git push
    # your first push to update your new remote repo with the current content
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gwang-jin-kim's answer, you can directly edit `(REPO_DIR)/.git/config` file.

If you open that file with your preferred editor, you'll see `[remote "origin"]`section.

In that section, modify `url = ...` for your new git URL (You can grab this URL by visiting your new repo on github web -> clone or download).

After doing that, `git push origin master` will push to your new upstream(repo).

However, according to your new repository setup you may encounter `push rejected...` error. In that case if you think your new repo's pre-existing commits do not matter you can add `-f(or --force)` option to drop your pre-existing commits.